# Incorrect version reference in Odata.svc for Microsoft.Data.Services

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

As a part of updating the data layer of our application (.NET Framework 4.5), I have to execute the Update Service Reference in Visual Studio for the client project. Recently, this has stopped working. I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
```

I checked, and the only place the text "5.3.0" appears in any file in my solution is in Odata.svc in the service project:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Service="<MyServiceProjectName>.OData" %>
```

The version of Microsoft.Data.Services.dll in my GAC_MSIL and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0\bin.NETFramework are 5.0.0.50627, but the ones in all of my project bin folder trees are 5.6.0.61587. I don't have a 5.3.* version of this dll anywhere. My project has the 5.6 versions of the WCF Data Services Client and the WCF Data Services Server NuGet packages installed.

My coworkers can successfully update the service reference, so it may be something on my machine that is wrong and not something in the solution. We are all using the latest version of all the files from our TFS source code repository. I've done a Build | Clean Solution and then a full Build and it made no difference.

How can I update Odata.svc to reference the 5.6 version or update my machine to have the 5.3 version where it is needed?

Comment: have you intstalled this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373

I had same situation, but was using wcf Odata + EF 6. that was hard challenge

Comment: Eugene: Are you suggesting that installing "WCF Data Services 5.6.0 RTM Tools Installer" will fix the problem, or that it might have caused the problem?  I don't recall having installed that.

Comment: I've had similar problems. That Tools Installer will update the templates that are used when you add or update a service reference to an odata source. It's not well publicized. It solved versioning problems, but I just want to note that it caused problems for me when using Lightswitch as an Odata client...but everything else worked fine.

Comment: Also, if you have a build process on your TFS, consider switching "Enable Nuget Restore" on so that the build server ensures it has the correct nuget package versions as well.

Comment: Installing the "WCF Data Services 5.6.0 RTM Tools Installer" had no effect on the issue. The problem seems to be that when I attempt to update the service reference on the client, the service is invoked and throws an exception because it thinks it should have version 5.3 of the dll and can't find it. Adding 5.6 doesn't help without updating the Odata.svc in the service to reference it, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have following markup in my service <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory, System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Service="Mebelle.Web.Services.MebelleDataService"  %>

Note WebServiceHostFactory, not a DataServiceHostFactory. It's WCF 5.6 + EF 6.0 source sample

Comment: Eugene: That seems to be an entirely different kind of reference. Is that in an Odata.svc file?